# Materializing the path of Nested Set hierarchy in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nested-sets

I have a table containing details on my company's chart of accounts - this data is essentially stored in nested sets (on SQL Server 2014), with each record having a left and right anchor - there are no Parent IDs.

Sample Data:

```
ID  LeftAnchor  RightAnchor  Name     
 1           0           25  Root     
 2           1           16  Group 1  
 3           2            9  Group 1.1
 4           3            4  Account 1
 5           5            6  Account 2
 6           7            8  Account 3
 7          10           15  Group 1.2
 8          11           12  Account 4
 9          13           14  Account 5
10          17           24  Group 2  
11          18           23  Group 2.1
12          19           20  Account 1
13          21           22  Account 1
```

I need to materialize the path for each record, so that my output looks like this:

```
ID  LeftAnchor  RightAnchor  Name       MaterializedPath
 1           0           25  Root       Root
 2           1           16  Group 1    Root > Group 1
 3           2            9  Group 1.1  Root > Group 1 > Group 1.1
 4           3            4  Account 1  Root > Group 1 > Group 1.1 > Account 1
 5           5            6  Account 2  Root > Group 1 > Group 1.1 > Account 2
 6           7            8  Account 3  Root > Group 1 > Group 1.1 > Account 3
 7          10           15  Group 1.2  Root > Group 1 > Group 1.2
 8          11           12  Account 4  Root > Group 1 > Group 1.2 > Acount 4
 9          13           14  Account 5  Root > Group 1 > Group 1.2 > Account 5
10          17           24  Group 2    Root > Group 2
11          18           23  Group 2.1  Root > Group 2 > Group 2.1
12          19           20  Account 1  Root > Group 2 > Group 2.1 > Account 10
13          21           22  Account 1  Root > Group 2 > Group 2.1 > Account 11
```

Whilst I've managed to achieve this using CTEs, the query is deathly slow. It takes just shy of two minutes to run with around 1200 records in the output.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
;with accounts as
(
    -- Chart of Accounts
    select AccountId, LeftAnchor, RightAnchor, Name
    from ChartOfAccounts
    -- dirty great where clause snipped
)
, parents as
(
    -- Work out the Parent Nodes
    select c.AccountId, p.AccountId [ParentId]
    from accounts c
    left join accounts p on (p.LeftAnchor = (
        select max(i.LeftAnchor)
        from accounts i
        where i.LeftAnchor<c.LeftAnchor
        and i.RightAnchor>c.RightAnchor
    ))
)
, path as
(
    -- Calculate the Account path for each node

    -- Root Node
    select c.AccountId, c.LeftAnchor, c.RightAnchor, 0 [Level], convert(varchar(max), c.name) [MaterializedPath]
    from accounts c
    where c.LeftAnchor = (select min(LeftAnchor) from chart)

    union all

    -- Children
    select n.AccountId, n.LeftAnchor, n.RightAnchor, p.level+1, p.path + ' > ' + n.name
    from accounts n
    inner join parents x on (n.AccountId=x.AccountId)
    inner join path p on (x.ParentId=p.AccountId)
)
select * from path order by LeftAnchor
```

Ideally this query should only take a couple of seconds (max) to run. I can't make any changes to the database itself (read-only connection), so can anyone come up with a better way to write this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your comments, I realized no need for the CTE... you already have the range keys.

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,Path = Replace(Path,'&gt;','>')
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Path = Stuff((Select ' > ' +Name 
                                      From (
                                            Select LeftAnchor,Name
                                             From  YourTable
                                             Where A.LeftAnchor between LeftAnchor and RightAnchor 
                                           ) B1
                                      Order By LeftAnchor
                                      For XML Path (''))
                                    ,1,6,'')
             ) B
 Order By LeftAnchor
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Excellent - using XML path has dropped execution time from almost 2 minutes down to 300ms. That's what I call a result!

Comment: I played this script on my data (mssql 2014) and get oddities, root folder has an output path like 'root > root > root > root' (4 levels depth in this example)

Comment: @barbara.post do you NOT have distinct Parent / Child relations?

Comment: JohnCappelletti not sure I understand youy question sorry. In addition to LeftAnchor and RighAnchor, I have a ParentId.
I just tried @BogdanSahlean 's proposal below and it works just fine. It may be slower but it seems convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd to me that you don't have a Parent ID, but with the aid of an initial `OUTER APPLY`, we can generate a Parent ID and then run a standard recursive CTE.

**Example**

```
Declare @Top int = null  --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 12 (Just for Fun)

;with cte0 as (
                Select A.* 
                      ,B.*
                 From  YourTable A
                 Outer Apply ( 
                                Select Top 1 Pt=ID 
                                 From  YourTable 
                                 Where A.LeftAnchor between LeftAnchor and RightAnchor and LeftAnchor<A.LeftAnchor 
                                 Order By LeftAnchor Desc
                              ) B
              ) 
     ,cteP as (
                  Select ID
                        ,Pt
                        ,LeftAnchor
                        ,RightAnchor
                        ,Lvl=1
                        ,Name 
                        ,Path = cast(Name as varchar(max))
                  From   cte0
                  Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(Pt ,-1) else ID end
                  Union  All
                  Select r.ID
                        ,r.Pt
                        ,r.LeftAnchor
                        ,r.RightAnchor
                        ,p.Lvl+1
                        ,r.Name 
                        ,cast(p.path + ' > '+r.Name as varchar(max))
                  From   cte0 r
                  Join   cteP p on r.Pt  = p.ID
              )
Select *
 From  cteP
 Order By LeftAnchor
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Alas, the data structures are defined by the application vendor, and for whatever reason they don't seem to care for adjacency lists. Thanks for the SQL - I'll give it a go and see what the performance looks like

Comment: @Pete Recursive CTEs are great, but performanc can suffer with larger hierarchies.  For example a temp table approach can build a 200K point hier in 4 seconds, while the recursive can take minutes

Comment: Yeah - I'm seeing that. The query will determine the Parent IDs in a fraction of a second - the killer is the recursive CTE that materializes the path. Unfortunately the approach of using an Outer Apply to generate Parent IDs hasn't made a difference to the overall execution time.

Answer (score 0):

First you can try to rearrange your preparing CTEs (accounts and parents) to have it that each CTE contains all data from previous, so you only use the last one in path CTE - no need for multiple joins:

```
;with accounts as
(
    -- Chart of Accounts
    select AccountId, LeftAnchor, RightAnchor, Name
    from ChartOfAccounts
    -- dirty great where clause snipped
)
, parents as
(
    -- Work out the Parent Nodes
    select c.*, p.AccountId [ParentId]
    from accounts c
    left join accounts p on (p.LeftAnchor = (
        select max(i.LeftAnchor)
        from accounts i
        where i.LeftAnchor<c.LeftAnchor
        and i.RightAnchor>c.RightAnchor
    ))
)
, path as
(
    -- Calculate the Account path for each node

    -- Root Node
    select c.AccountId, c.LeftAnchor, c.RightAnchor, 0 [Level], convert(varchar(max), c.name) [MaterializedPath]
    from parents c
    where c.ParentID IS NULL

    union all

    -- Children
    select n.AccountId, n.LeftAnchor, n.RightAnchor, p.level+1, p.[MaterializedPath] + ' > ' + n.name
    from parents n
    inner join path p on (n.ParentId=p.AccountId)
)
select * from path order by LeftAnchor
```

This should give some improvement (50% in my test), but to have it really better, you can split first half of preparing data into #temp table, put clustered index on ParentID column in #temp table and use it in second part

```
if (Object_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE #tmp;
with accounts as
(
    -- Chart of Accounts
    select AccountId, LeftAnchor, RightAnchor, Name
    from ChartOfAccounts
    -- dirty great where clause snipped
)
, parents as
(
    -- Work out the Parent Nodes
    select c.*, p.AccountId [ParentId]
    from accounts c
    left join accounts p on (p.LeftAnchor = (
        select max(i.LeftAnchor)
        from accounts i
        where i.LeftAnchor<c.LeftAnchor
        and i.RightAnchor>c.RightAnchor
    ))
)
select * into #tmp
from parents;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_tmp1 ON #tmp (ParentID);

With path as
(
    -- Calculate the Account path for each node

    -- Root Node
    select c.AccountId, c.LeftAnchor, c.RightAnchor, 0 [Level], convert(varchar(max), c.name) [MaterializedPath]
    from #tmp c
    where c.ParentID IS NULL

    union all

    -- Children
    select n.AccountId, n.LeftAnchor, n.RightAnchor, p.level+1, p.[MaterializedPath] + ' > ' + n.name
    from #tmp n
    inner join path p on (n.ParentId=p.AccountId)
)
select * from path order by LeftAnchor
```

Hard to tell on small sample data, but it should be an improvement. Please tell if you try it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I'm stuck with a read-only connection, so I can't create temp tables or indexes. Although I could Declare @temp Table in the code, the performance issue seems to be more around the use of recursive CTEs on a dataset of this size

Comment: @Pete Are you sure? There are no special permissions to create temp tables. Anyone who can connect to DB should be able to do it.

Comment: @Pete Added a second answer